# Critical Error message of Wordpress adming

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

We have website on Wordpress and hosted on AWS server. There is a critical error message is coming on Wordpress adding when we are trying to add new post or image. (PFA screenshot for reference)

Can anyone help us in resolving this If they know this problem.  
[image]Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the email with instructions that it says you were sent? Did you click the learn more link and read that? With no information, nobody here is going to be able to tell you any more than those.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your dashboard, deactivate all the plugins and activate it one by one, and check your website. If you are not able to access your WP Dashboard because of this error. Go to your hosting Cpanel > File Manager > Public_html > wp-content, rename the plugin folder, and then check your website.

Go to Dashboard > plugins, you will see all your plugins have been deactivated. Again goto Cpanel and rename the plugin folder to its original name "plugins".

After that, go to your Dashboard > Plugins > and activate it one by one.

Comment: That might help, yes, but I think reading the error email the site generated and checking the server logs for errors would be a better first step.